# Why won't this left join query return all the rows in the left table?

Tags: ms-access

Using MS-Access 2016. Been dabbling in databases for years but am strictly an amateur. I am probably missing some obvious answer but have not been able to find it with all my "left join only showing one row" searches. Never had this problem in Paradox (DOS)! Here's some sample data that shows where I am stuck.

```
Table 1 - Customers

CustID* | Name
1       | Jane Doe
2       | Jill Doe
3       | John Doe

Table 2 - Orders

OrderID* | CustID | Order
1        | 1      | Orange
2        | 1      | Banana
3        | 2      | Orange
4        | 2      | Apple
5        | 2      | Banana
6        | 3      | Apple
7        | 3      | Strawberry
8        | 3      | Banana
```

**I want a list of all the customers that show whether they have or have not had a strawberry**. That is, the results should look like:

```
Name      | Order
Jane Doe  | (null)
Jill Doe  | (null)
John Doe  | Strawberry
```

The query I am using is:

```
SELECT Customers.Name, Orders.Order
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustID = Orders.CustID
WHERE (((Orders.Order)="Strawberry"));
```

What it returns is: 
    John Doe | Strawberry

Could some kind soul please tell me what I am missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customers.Name, Orders.Order
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustID = Orders.CustID
WHERE (((Orders.Order)="Strawberry"));
```

only returns customers that ordered strawberries. You need to clarify that you also want customers that did not order strawberries.

The issue is because all entris in Customers table do have possible join partners (i. e. not strawberry but something else) they do not appear as NULL in your LEFT JOIN. Therefore you need to query again for Customers that did not order strawberry.

You also need  `OR o.Order IS NULL` for the case if a customer did not order anything yet.

```
(SELECT c.Name, o.Order
FROM Customers AS c LEFT jOIN Orders AS o ON c.CustID = o.CustID
WHERE o.Order = 'Strawberry' OR o.Order IS NULL
GROUP BY c.Name, o.Order)

UNION

SELECT c.Name, null
FROM Customers AS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT Orders.CustID 
  FROM Orders 
  WHERE c.CustID = Orders.CustID AND Orders.Order = 'Strawberry'
)

ORDER BY c.Name, o.Order
```

I think the Access database engine messes with your standard SQL logic. I often found Access SQL especially cumbersome. Like here you have to use an group by and ordery by to make this union query work.

Comment: Already tried that. Doesn't work. Returns one record: John Doe | Strawberry. There are no records in Orders.Order that meet the criteria of "Is Null", at least in Access 2016.

Comment: Actually, why would I have to supply any additional selection criteria when the Left Join, by its very nature, should supply all all the records in the Left table? That's what's so weird about this.

Comment: The left join has no affect if you include a where condition on it. There is a different syntax that can be used to include outer joins with additional criteria but access does not support such joins. To do this in access, you need your left join to reference a subquery or an actual query that has that Strawberry criteria.

Answer (score 0):

here is what i meant. I assume you used the column name for illustration, otherwise the name [Order] is a reserved word and should not be used for table/column names.

```
SELECT a.Name, b.[Order]
FROM Customers a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Orders Where [Order] = 'Strawberry') b
 on a.CustID = b.CustID
```